# Problem with jQuery's order of effects

Tags: jquery, effects

I would like to [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) a button, then [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) the response an Ajax call. The response is a a new button. What the following code does, however, is `fadeOut` the first button, fade it back in, then replace it with the new one. I tried a few combinations but could not get it to work. where did I go wrong?

```
beforeSend: function()
{
    $(this).fadeOut("slow");
},

success: function(response)
{
    $(this).fadeIn("slow", function () {
        $(this).parent().html(response);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` inside an AJAX call is not the previous element anymore. You must store it in a var previous to the AJAX call, like:

`var button = $(this);`

and later:

`button.fadeOut();`

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (note the mistyped "show" on fadeOut):

```
beforeSend: function()
{
    $(this).fadeOut("slow");
},

success: function(response)
{
    $(this).parent().html(response);
    $(this).stop().fadeIn("slow");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).parent().html(response);` would effectively eliminate `this`.  So changing it to this should fix it:

```
$(this).parent().html(response);
$("#thething").stop().fadeIn("slow");
```

where #thething is the id of "this"

EDIT: also what morgar said.